# Build Fails: redefinition; different basic types & type name first seen using 'class' now seen using 'struct'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm using VS 2010 Ultimate.  Toolset v90.

I've got a DLL and a Test Project that statically links to the DLL.  Inside the DLL is a class that is exported called IFilter.  This interface class is wrapped inside a namespace, the usage of said class is explicitly spelled out using the namespace e.g.
    void DoSomethingWithDLLTypes( const Observer::IFilter &);

Everything has been working fine for months, however, with recent changes outside the DLL project I began pulling in new files.  As I was adding these files to the solution, rebuilding with each add to test, all was working well then suddenly I got this error.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\Filter.h(53): warning C4099: 'Observer::IFilter' : type name first seen using 'class' now seen using 'struct'
d:\proj\pub\h\IFilter.h(12) : see declaration of 'Observer::IFilter'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\Filter.h(183): error C2371: 'IFilter' : redefinition; different basic types
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\Filter.h(53) : see declaration of 'IFilter'

Originally IFilter was not wrapped in a namespace, so I had to go through all my files (thinking this would solve it) and wrap everything in a namespace.  Now, the DLL compiles just fine, however, I still get this same error in the Test Project.  I don't even know how/why IFilter/Filter.h from the MS SDK is being included.

The Test project uses precompiled headers, however, it isn't using Windows.h, either way I went ahead and did the #define lean_and_mean macro in there "just to be sure", didn't help anything.

Comment: IFilter is an interface for windows indexing service plugins. Something in your project is including a header file that pulls the definition in. Change your project settings to dump the include file hierarchy during compilation and see if you can trace it to the point of origin.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: The error message names the two headers that declare the type, there is no need to dump the whole hierarchy (unless you want to know *why* it was included, rather than *what* was included)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Knowing why might be a good idea in case he runs into it again.

Answer (score 1):

One of the places where the Visual Studio compiler does not comply with the standard. According to the standard, the `struct` and `class` keywords can be used interchangeably to declare the same type, but VS has different mangling for types defined as `struct` and `class` so it requires that you consistently use one or the other keyword for your type.

Now, the error points to two seemingly unrelated header files, so it might just be a clash in names:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\Filter.h
d:\proj\pub\h\IFilter.h
```

In the first header there is a `class Observer::IFilter`, and in the second header you have `struct Observer::IFilter`. If they are the same, then you should fix the project so that it does not include multiple headers with the definition, if they are different things, then you should make the names unique (add a namespace)

Comment: Last time I checked VS did not *require* one to use `struct` and `class` consistently and it did not affect name mangling. I.e. the compiler's behavior was perfectly compliant. Issuing a warning in such case is a good idea, since the situation suggests a potential unintentional name clash.

Comment: @AndreyT: I seem to recall that this was an issue in the past. I must admit that I have not used VS for quite a long time, and they might have corrected this in the compiler (mangling the symbols in the same way) or even the linker (treating both symbols as aliases, for example)

Comment: I can't check older versions of VS compiler, but VS2005 doesn't seem to have any mangling-related issues with mixing `struct` and `class`. It does issue a warning, but nevertheless treats them the same.

Comment: The IFilter.h that I have defined is wrapped in a namespace and is  a class.  I never use the 'using namespace' anywhere in the dll for any namespace, everything is spelled out explicitly.  The other header, which defines it's type as a struct, is part of the Microsoft SDK.  How the names colide, with one wrapped in a namespace is beyond me.  The ultimate fix was I had to rename my class altogether, I don't know why.